# Paytm Payment Gateway UPI integration in Python backend

Tags: payment-gateway, paytm, upi

I am trying to integrate Paytm payment gateway to my website for UPI transactions only, So after going through the documentation, I was able to integrate the [Initate payment](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/initiate-transaction-api/) API but when I am trying to integrate the [validate VPA](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/validate-vpa/) API, it always gives VPA invalid, I am adding the code for reference, I am replacing `my_mid` with correct MID, `my_key` with a correct key and also `7777777777@paytm` with a valid VPA

```
import requests
import json
paytmParams = dict()
paytmParams["body"] = {
    "vpa" : "7777777777@paytm"
}
paytmParams["head"] = {
    "txnToken" : "4f7197de6840450e9162ddb5c067eb221590561957267"
}
post_data = json.dumps(paytmParams)
url = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/vpa/validate?mid=my_mid&orderId=123abcd"
response = requests.post(url, data = post_data, headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}).json()
print(response)
```

Executing this always returns,

```
{
  "head": {
    "requestId": None,
    "responseTimestamp": "1590561981014",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "body": {
    "extraParamsMap": None,
    "resultInfo": {
      "resultStatus": "F",
      "resultCode": "501",
      "resultMsg": "Sorry! We could not verify the VPA."
    },
    "vpa": "7777777777@paytm",
    "valid": False
  }
}
```

The `txnToken` is obtained from the below code irrespective of the VPA,

```
import requests
import json
import hashlib
import base64
import string
import random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

IV = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$"
BLOCK_SIZE = 16

def __pad__(s): return s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) %
                            BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)

def __encode__(to_encode, iv, key):
    to_encode = __pad__(to_encode)
    c = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    to_encode = c.encrypt(to_encode)
    to_encode = base64.b64encode(to_encode)
    return to_encode.decode("UTF-8")

def __id_generator__(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

def generate_checksum_by_str(param_str, merchant_key, salt=None):
    params_string = param_str
    salt = salt if salt else __id_generator__(4)
    final_string = '%s|%s' % (params_string, salt)
    hasher = hashlib.sha256(final_string.encode())
    hash_string = hasher.hexdigest()
    hash_string += salt
    return __encode__(hash_string, IV, merchant_key)

paytmParams = dict()
paytmParams["body"] = {
    "requestType": "Payment",
    "mid": "my_mid",
    "websiteName": "WEBSTAGING",
    "orderId": "123abcd",
    "txnAmount": {
        "value": "500",
        "currency": "INR",
    },
    "userInfo": {
        "custId": "1234567",
    },
    "enablePaymentMode":  [{"mode": "UPI", "channels": ["UPIPUSH"]}]
}
checksum = generate_checksum_by_str(
    json.dumps(paytmParams["body"]), "my_key")
paytmParams["head"] = {
    "signature" : checksum
}
post_data = json.dumps(paytmParams)
url = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=my_mid&orderId=123abcd"
response = requests.post(url, data=post_data, headers={
                         "Content-type": "application/json"}).json()
print(response)
```

Please let me know if any more details are required, as I have done all kind of research but did not get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any issue with your code. May be you can try out one more time. if you still face the issue, please reach out to the support of Paytm developer.